# Should UserControls have InitializeComponent in its constructor?

Tags: .net, wpf, user-controls

In WPF should I include `InitializeComponent()` in the user control constructor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`InitializeComponent` binds the XAML-defined child controls (those with the attribute `x:Name`) to the fields defined in the class. So, you should have `InitializeComponent` at the class which uses XAML for definition. You cannot do this in the base class, because it doesn't know those fields. (Beside that `InitializeComponent` parses the XAML and creates the visual elements, but this is not important for now).

This means, if your control is defined with XAML, you should have InitializeComponent. If you don't use XAML (but just overriding something in constructor or adding some more properties/features), you don't need InitializeComponent.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, when this method is called, the XAML for your control is parsed and the various elements created.

Comment: But shouldn't I delegate this responsibility to the Form constructor? Imagine that I don't want to initialize twice.

Comment: You don't initialize twice.  The Form's InitializeComponent will result in the child controls' InitializeComponent being called, and so on down your control hierarchy.  Leave the call in place.